Why is multiplication of integer O(n^2)?
I was wondering why multiplication of integers is O(n^2)? I've been taught addition and multiplication is considered 1 operation. Hence if I multiply an integer of n-digits with another integer of n-digits I should get O(n^2), which is true. But can someone explain it to me with an example.
Example
If I want to multiply 99 x 99. I can only count 3 operations

99 x 9
99 x 90
891 + 8910
Which would only give me O(3) when it should be O(4).


If we're considering arbitrarily large integers, 99 * 9 cannot be considered constant time.

Also, big O says something about asymptotic complexity. So O(n²-1) is the same as O(n²).

While O(f) is a statement of an upper bound: stating an asymptotic lower bound on a problem for one class of machines is a statement about all algorithms that apply, known as well as yet to be conceived. "Long multiplication" is n² - try with two different 7-digit factors.

Multiplication is not O(n^2).
Multiplication of integers with a bounded number of digits is O(1), because all operations on bounded-size inputs are O(1).
Multiplication of unbounded-size integers requires O(n log n) time, using the algorithms with best-known complexity.
Certain simple multiplication algorithms are O(n^2), but they are only appropriate for small-ish sized integers.  These algorithms work like the one you use when you multiply with pencil and paper.  Try multiplying 8194421 * 3882342 using the method you learned in school.  You'll find that you end up writing about 50 digits.

There are multiple cost models used in analysis of algorithms.
In computer science theory, bit complexity or something similar is used. The number of steps required in this model is essentially the number of steps some Turing machine would use, each step operating on only a fixed number bits at a time. The program input is a string of n bits. Simply copying an input would have complexity O(n), since each bit must be processed. The elementary-school algorithm for multiplication is O(n2) in this model, but better algorithms are O(n log n).
In analysis of algorithms for practical purposes, a uniform cost per machine operation may be used. In this model, multiplication of two numbers in processor registers is O(1). This model is reasonable and useful for commercial purposes because it accurately reflects the increasing costs of increasing workloads as long as the data fits into processor words or some other fixed-size unit that is used for measurement. For example, for a company that has a n customers, the cost of inserting a new record into an ordered database may be O(log n) because the only thing that changes for them as n grows is how many records they have to compare to find the insertion spot. They do not actually have to handle more bytes per key as n grows, since there are already enough bytes in the keys to handle all the n they will ever encounter.
This cost model breaks when the word size is exceeded. It is not a true mathematical model of complexity, because the O notation is defined as a statement about “For all n…,” but the practical complexity model only works up to n for which the data fits into the fixed-size unit. However, it is useful for many practical purposes.

Let's start with something from the example. You write:

Which would only give me O(3) when it should be O(4).

Your expectation about big-O is wrong. Big-O does not tell you the exact number of constant time operations (aka O(1) operations) to be performed. You can't insert some n value an expect to get the exact number of O(1) operations.
As an example consider an algorithm that requires exactly 41*n^2 + 45*n + 42 O(1) operations, the big-O complexity will be said to O(n^2). Big-O only cares about the most the most dominant part, i.e. the part that contributes most as n keeps growing. And even for the most dominant part big-O ignores any multiplications with constant.
The purpose of big-O is simply not to get the number of O(1) operations. The purpose is to give an idea about how execution time will change as n gets higher and higher. Not an exact time - just an idea. Let's say that for some nvalue, e.g. n = 1.000, you have measured execution time to be T. If you run the same algorithm with n = 10.000, i.e. 10 times higher, and the algorithm is O(n^2) then then execution time can be expected to be about 100 times higher, i.e. 10 * 10 * T. Not exactly... but that's the trend for sufficiently high values of n. Big-O is not exact. It's a rough indication of what you can expect when n grows higher and higher.
The you write:

I've been taught addition and multiplication is considered 1 operation.

Well... Correct and wrong!
In order to calculate big-O complexity, it is important that prerequisites are clear. They are not in the question.
If we are talking about addition/multiplication of integers that have an upper/lower value limit then it's correct. As you can't let the input grow towards infinity, the execution time can't grow towards infinity. In a specific implementation it could be that some values result in faster execution than other values but since there is a worst case with fixed excution, big-O consider it O(1).
If we are talking integers with unlimited upper/lower values then it's wrong. Here the input and consequently the execution time has no upper limit so it's not O(1).
Going back to the example:
It seems you conside e.g. 99 x 9 as "one O(1) opreration". Is it? Can you calculate 99 x 9 in the same time as 9 x 12345678900987654321123456789?
I can't.
To repeat:
In order to calculate big-O complexity, it is important that prerequisites are clear. Which operation are O(1) operations?
If I were to do a multiplication using pen and paper, I would consider a 1-digit multiplication/addition as the basic O(1) operation. Operations on multiple digits should then be done using those basic O(1) operation.
For instance 123 x 456:
First the multiplication part:

123 x 456
---------
     1368
     9120
    45600

Except for the right most zeros, each digit in each row requires a basic multiplication and a basic (addition for the carry). That's 2 O(1) operations for each digit. But in big-O we just say O(1), i.e. constant time.
Again ignore the right most zeros, the worst case number of digits is 3 * (3 + 1). Or in general n * (n + 1) or n^2 + n digits. Since each digit is O(1), we  have n^2 + n O(1) operations. As previously mention big-O only cares about the most the most dominant part so the + n is ignored and we end up with O(n^2) for the first part of the multiplication.
Now the second part of the calculation is to add the 3 rows (in general n rows) to get:
123 x 456
---------
     1368
     9120
    45600
---------
    56088

I'll leave it to the reader to calculate the big-O complexity for doing the add....
If it's less than O(n^2) then the final complexity is O(n^2).
If it's O(n^2) then the final complexity is still O(n^2).
If it's more than O(n^2) then that's the final complexity.


I was wondering why multiplication of integers is O(n^2)?

If you consider multiplying two n-digits numbers with the common multiplying algorithm, then this is true. But there exists more efficient multiplication algorithms. It is known that multiply cost is at least O(n.log(n)), i.e. multiplying is more costly than adding.

I've been taught addition and multiplication is considered 1
operation.

The problem is that when you evaluate complexity of an algorithm you have to fix what are the basic operations, the ones that have O(1) cost. In general we consider basic arithmetic operations as such because in real computers these operations have a bounded constant cost. But, if for example, you try to evaluate complexity of an algorithm in which there is unbounded numbers, you will need to consider the cost of arithmetic operations on them.
Suppose you evaluate the complexity of this:
function integer multiply(integer a, integer b) {
    // blah blah
}

If your integers are bounded, then the cost will be a constant, because for all possible values there is a maximum cost, thus the complexity is O(1). In some way you can degrade this function to a lookup table with all the possible results, thus the cost will be clearly constant (if you agree that accessing an element in a lookup table is constant).
If your integers are not bounded, the cost will be the cost of the algorithm used.
